# Populate Highcharts series with data from AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I have a container `<div class="statsrep"></div>` where I want to show my chart/graph. I want to populate the chart's data with the data that from my AJAX/JSON but it seems to be not working. The chart gives me this (look closely at the categories/dates):

[image]

What could possibly be the cause of this?

The AJAX/JSON response is:

```
{
  "dates": "'2014-01-06','2014-01-07','2014-01-08','2014-01-09','2014-01-12','2014-01-13','2014-01-14','2014-01-15','2014-01-16','2014-01-19','2014-01-20','2014-01-21','2014-01-22','2014-01-23','2014-01-26'",
  "leadsTotal": "260,474,689,851,1104,1268,1439,1588,1726,2021,2216,2395,2587,2756,3002",
  "leadQuote": "11,12,12,14,14,15,15,15,16,14,15,16,15,15,15",
  "salesConv": "3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,6,6,5,5,5",
  "totalIMU": "15418.95,21875.09,32555.79,41962.11,53790.88,59817.54,64005.61,72176.84,74874.39,83949.47,98021.05,106736.84,109518.60,117886.32,124241.40",
  "vpl": "59.30,46.15,47.25,49.31,48.72,47.17,44.48,45.45,43.38,41.54,44.23,44.57,42.33,42.77,41.39"
}
```

and here's my AJAX request:

```
var date = $('#frankdate').val();
var aff = $('#affID').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'graphMerchantTotal.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        merchant:"frank",
        date: date,
        aff: aff
    },
    success:function(json){
        $('#statsrep').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Frank Daily Stats',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Overall Total',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: json.dates
            },
            yAxis: {
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {

            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Leads',
                data: json.leadsTotal
            }, {
                name: 'Lead to Quote (%)',
                data: json.leadQuote
            }, {
                name: 'Sale Conversion (%)',
                data: json.salesConv
            }, {
                name: 'Total After IMU',
                data: json.totalIMU
            }, {
                name: 'VPL',
                data: json.vpl
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The response text from the AJAX request should be returning a string, so you first have to eval() that string before javascript can use it as an actual object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use array of numbers in your series, but in your case you have only strings with points, separated by commas. You need to use split() function and push into new array, then use in highcharts.

Comment: Thanks, I've used split and then mapped them as numeric values.